# Is there Anyway to add tooltip in a readonly textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I want to add tooltip in a readonly fields by using jquery. read data from readonly textbox and show as tooltip. I am not able to find its solution anywhere in google

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nextDate').keyup(function () {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).val())
    })
})
```

html

```
 <td><input type="text" title="" id="nextdate" class="form-control" readonly=""/></td>
```

but it doesn't works

Comment: It doesn't work because there is no `title` on the element by default and your code to set the `title` will never run as it's set on the `keyup` event yet the element is `readonly` so the key events can never happen. I'm not sure what you're expecting here.

Comment: I am expecting to read value from readonly field and show it as tooltip.

Comment: My code is working for normal fields but this code is not working in case of readonly fields

Comment: I think keyup will not support on readonly field.Better you try some other event like on-focus-out ....

Comment: It doesn't works on on-focus as well is there any plugin for this you know about?

Comment: Not sure if you are able to get this or not but your code is not working as `keyup` event is not fired at all on read-only elements. If you are setting the field value anywhere else then set the title there only and it will work fine.

Comment: have u using any date picker plugin for that field  ?

Comment: No, it is just done by html5

Comment: try mouse over event

Comment: mouse-over event will work

Comment: <td><input readonly="Attribute Value" value="input value" /></td>
Please confirm are you getting "Attribute Value" or "input value"

Answer (score 0):

I am using **mouse over** event instead of **keyup event**.May be it will be useful for you.

```
  <td><input type="text" title="hello" id="nextdate" class="form-control" value="2020-10-10" readonly="" onmouseover="myFunction()"/></td>
<script>
function myFunction(){
 document.getElementById('nextdate').setAttribute('title',   document.getElementById('nextdate').value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I want to read value which is in readonly field it is not reading right now

Comment: are using any event to bind the value in the  nextdate field ??

Answer (score 0):

You should not insert any string inside readonly, Inside readonly should be true/false or readonly="readonly", if you insert any custom string like readonly="Hi this is readonly".
This will make input readonly in smart browsers like chrome but It may be break in old browsers. So if you would like to show any custom message then you can create and custom attribute like this:

```
 <input type="text" readonly="readonly" data-readonly="hi, i am readonly" value="Hi i am input3" />
```

And you can get this value through:

```
$(this).attr('data-readonly')
```

you can check this fiddle also:
https://jsfiddle.net/nr06Lmte/